# Error parsing graphql schema in Springboot, how to fix it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I have a project where I am using Springboot with GraphQL.

Im using Java11 with Gradle 5.6.2.

In my module I have added these dependencies for GraphQl.

```
    // GraphQl
    implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.10.0'
    implementation 'com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2'
    implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:voyager-spring-boot-starter:5.10.0'
    implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-java-tools:5.6.1'
```

In my `src/main/java/no.domain.project` i have my SpringbootApplication. I also have a folder called `RootResolver` where i have added following class:

```
@Component
public class RootResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver{

    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

My `schema.graphqls` have following Query:

```
type Query {
    hello: String!
}
```

I can access `localhost:8080/grapiql` with 404.

But when i run the project i get following errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLHttpServlet' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLHttpServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletConfiguration' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletConfiguration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'options'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParserOptions' defined in no.inmeta.ris.web.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserOptions]: Factory method 'schemaParserOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationInterceptor

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLHttpServlet' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLHttpServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletConfiguration' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletConfiguration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'options'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParserOptions' defined in no.inmeta.ris.web.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserOptions]: Factory method 'schemaParserOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationInterceptor

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletConfiguration' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletConfiguration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'options'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParserOptions' defined in no.inmeta.ris.web.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserOptions]: Factory method 'schemaParserOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationInterceptor

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'options'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParserOptions' defined in no.inmeta.ris.web.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserOptions]: Factory method 'schemaParserOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationInterceptor

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'options'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParserOptions' defined in no.inmeta.ris.web.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserOptions]: Factory method 'schemaParserOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationInterceptor

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'options'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParserOptions' defined in no.inmeta.ris.web.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserOptions]: Factory method 'schemaParserOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationInterceptor

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParserOptions' defined in no.inmeta.ris.web.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserOptions]: Factory method 'schemaParserOptions' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationInterceptor
```

I shorted down the error message.

What causes this problem. I see that it not picking up my schema but why is that so? I have seen lot of tutorials where I do the same, but I am getting this error.

Any advice?

Thank for help!

Comment: I also see you have a typo in the graphiql endpoint. I think it should be `localhost:8080/graphiql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out :) I needed to add a `gradle.properties` file and add `kotlin.version=1.3.50` because when you start `SpringApplication` you will get error `NoClassDefFoundException` because `Spring Boot` overwrites the Kotlin version which library is using.